# DevExtreme select-option with Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, devextreme

I'm trying to populate a **DevExtreme** *SelectBox()* (or a *Lookup()*) with a `Dictionary<string><string>` but I'm getting error:

> Uncaught Error: E4006 - ArrayStore 'data' option must be an array.

**Model**

```
public string Lang { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> Languages { get; }

...

this.Lang = "es";

this.Languages = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"en", "English"},  {"ar", "Arabic"},     {"bn", "Bengali"},   {"cs", "Czech"},      {"da", "Danish"},    {"de", "German"},
                                                    {"el", "Greek"},    {"es", "Spanish"},    {"fa", "Persian"},   {"fi", "Finnish"},    {"fil", "Filipino"}, {"fr", "French"},
                                                    {"he", "Hebrew"},   {"hi", "Hindi"},      {"hu", "Hungarian"}, {"id", "Indonesian"}, {"it", "Italian"},   {"ja", "Japanese"},
                                                    {"ko", "Korean"},   {"msa", "Malay"},     {"nl", "Dutch"},     {"no", "Norwegian"},  {"pl", "Polish"},    {"pt", "Portuguese"},
                                                    {"ro", "Romanian"}, {"ru", "Russian"},    {"sv", "Swedish"},   {"th", "Thai"},       {"tr", "Turkish"},   {"uk", "Ukrainian"},
                                                    {"ur", "Urdu"},     {"vi", "Vietnamese"}, {"zh-cn", "Chinese (Simplified)"},         {"zh-tw", "Chinese (Traditional)"} };
```

**View**

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form()
        .ID("form")
        .FormData(Model)
        .ColCount(12)
        .ShowValidationSummary(true)
        .Items(i =>
        {
            i.AddSimple()
            .ColSpan(6)
            .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
            .DataField(Model.Lang.ToString())
            .Editor(ed => ed.SelectBox()
                            .DataSource(Model.Languages)
                            .Placeholder("Language..."));
        }))
```

I've tried making a `List`, which doesn't returns error but won't show anything.

**Model**

```
public string Lang { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> Languages { get; }
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> List { get; }

...

this.Lang = "es";

this.Languages = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"en", "English"},  {"ar", "Arabic"},     {"bn", "Bengali"},   {"cs", "Czech"},      {"da", "Danish"},    {"de", "German"},
                                                    {"el", "Greek"},    {"es", "Spanish"},    {"fa", "Persian"},   {"fi", "Finnish"},    {"fil", "Filipino"}, {"fr", "French"},
                                                    {"he", "Hebrew"},   {"hi", "Hindi"},      {"hu", "Hungarian"}, {"id", "Indonesian"}, {"it", "Italian"},   {"ja", "Japanese"},
                                                    {"ko", "Korean"},   {"msa", "Malay"},     {"nl", "Dutch"},     {"no", "Norwegian"},  {"pl", "Polish"},    {"pt", "Portuguese"},
                                                    {"ro", "Romanian"}, {"ru", "Russian"},    {"sv", "Swedish"},   {"th", "Thai"},       {"tr", "Turkish"},   {"uk", "Ukrainian"},
                                                    {"ur", "Urdu"},     {"vi", "Vietnamese"}, {"zh-cn", "Chinese (Simplified)"},         {"zh-tw", "Chinese (Traditional)"} };

this.List = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>() { this.Languages };
```

**View**

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form()
        .ID("form")
        .FormData(Model)
        .ColCount(12)
        .ShowValidationSummary(true)
        .Items(i =>
        {
            i.AddSimple()
            .ColSpan(6)
            .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
            .DataField(Model.Lang.ToString())
            .Editor(ed => ed.SelectBox()
                            .DataSource(Model.List)
                            .Placeholder("Language..."));
        }))
```

[image: SelectBox()]

Answer (score 1):

*ArrayStore 'data' option must be an array* indicates that you're not passing proper object (i.e. array object) to the data source of `SelectBox` (note that `Dictionary<string, string>` cannot be directly translated to a single-dimension array required by `dataSource` object).

In case of this is DevExtreme in ASP.NET MVC, you may try creating base model class for language list like this:

```
public class Language
{
    public string LangID { get; set; }

    public string LangName { get; set; }
}
```

Note that it's necessary to have `List<Language>` property in target viewmodel, e.g. `List<Language> Languages { get; set; }`. Then build the list of languages as in example below:

**Controller Action**

```
this.Lang = "es";

this.Languages = new List<Language>() {
                     new Language { LangID = "en", LangName = "English" },
                     new Language { LangID = "el", LangName = "Greek" },
                     // other language definitions
                 };

// convert to JSON format and return this into view
this.LangArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Languages);
```

**View**

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form()
        .ID("form")
        .FormData(Model)
        .ColCount(12)
        .ShowValidationSummary(true)
        .Items(i =>
        {
            i.AddSimple()
            .ColSpan(6)
            .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
            .DataField(Model.Lang.ToString())
            .Editor(ed => ed.SelectBox()
                            .DataSource(Model.LangArray)
                            .DisplayExpr("LangName") // displayed text
                            .ValueExpr("LangID") // selected value for submit
                            .Placeholder("Language..."));
        }))
```

**Additional note:**

If you still want to use `Dictionary`, make sure you convert it to a string **which conforms JSON key-value pair format**:

```
public static string ToJsonArray(this Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    var kvp = dict.Select(x => string.Format(@"""{0}"":""{1}""", x.Key, string.Concat(",", x.Value)));
    return string.Concat("{", string.Join(",", kvp), "}");
}

// Usage
this.LangArray = this.Languages.ToJsonArray();
```

References:

[DataSource API Reference](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/)

[SelectBox API Reference](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/Configuration/#dataSource)

[SelectBox Example](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/SelectBox/SearchAndEditing/Mvc/Light/)

Comment: I've found a _workaround_. Not pretty, but a with less changes. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been able to solve this using **Linq**, creating the *array* on the fly:

```
i.AddSimple()
    .ColSpan(6)
    .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
    .DataField(Model.Lang)
    .Editor(ed => ed.SelectBox()
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.Array().Key("value").Data(Model.Languages.Select(s => new { value = s.Key, text = s.Value })))
                    .Value(Model.Lang)
                    .ValueExpr("value")
                    .DisplayExpr("text")
                    .Placeholder("Language..."));
```

Comment: Also, in `DataField` you want to pass the name of the field, not the value, so `.DataField("Lang")`. Then you don't need `.Value(Model.Lang)` anymore.